How can I fix errors in my MQL4 code for weekly profit summary generation?
I’m working on an MQL4 function to generate a weekly profit summary for my trading strategy. The function retrieves historical order data and categorizes it into weekly periods to calculate total profits and losses.
I’ve implemented the logic for both monthly and weekly summaries, but I’m now focusing solely on weekly summaries. I would like to ensure my code is error-free and efficient.
Here’s the code I’m working with:
    string ProfitSummary(int magicNumber) {
    string msg_ProfitSummary = "";
    datetime currentTime = TimeCurrent();
    int hstTotal = OrdersHistoryTotal();

    double totalProfit = 0.0;
    double totalLoss = 0.0;

    datetime starttime = 0; // Start time of the period
    datetime endtime = 0; // End time of the period

    static datetime lastProcessedTime = 0; // Keep track of the last processed period start time

    // Initialize `lastProcessedTime` based on the period type if it's the first run
    if (lastProcessedTime == 0) {
        int currentYear = TimeYear(currentTime);
        datetime firstDayOfYear = StringToTime(IntegerToString(currentYear) + ".01.01 00:00");
        int firstWeekday = TimeDayOfWeek(firstDayOfYear);

        // Get the weekday of the current day (1=Sunday, 2=Monday, ..., 7=Saturday)
        int currentWeekday = TimeDayOfWeek(currentTime);

        // Calculate the start of the current week (Monday)
        int daysFromMonday = (currentWeekday + 6) % 7;
        datetime startOfCurrentWeek = currentTime - daysFromMonday * 24 * 3600;

        // Start of the previous week
        lastProcessedTime = startOfCurrentWeek - 7 * 24 * 3600;
    }

    // Process until the current period
    while (lastProcessedTime < currentTime) {
        // Set start and end times for each week
        starttime = lastProcessedTime;
        endtime = starttime + 7 * 24 * 3600; // Span 7 days for the next week

        // Debugging output
        Print("Processing period: Start = ", TimeToStr(starttime, TIME_DATE | TIME_MINUTES),
            ", End = ", TimeToStr(endtime, TIME_DATE | TIME_MINUTES));

        // Reset totals for the period
        totalProfit = 0.0;
        totalLoss = 0.0;

        // Calculate profit/loss
        for (int i = 0; i < hstTotal; i++) {
            if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY)) {
                if (OrderMagicNumber() == magicNumber &&
                    OrderCloseTime() >= starttime && OrderCloseTime() < endtime &&
                    (OrderType() == OP_BUY || OrderType() == OP_SELL)) {
                    double orderProfitZAR = (OrderProfit() + OrderSwap() + OrderCommission());

                    // Categorize closure type
                    if (OrderClosePrice() == OrderStopLoss() && orderProfitZAR < 0) {
                        totalLoss += orderProfitZAR;
                    } else if (OrderClosePrice() == OrderTakeProfit() && orderProfitZAR > 0) {
                        totalProfit += orderProfitZAR;
                    } else {
                        if (orderProfitZAR > 0)
                            totalProfit += orderProfitZAR;
                        else
                            totalLoss += orderProfitZAR;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Print("Failed to select order at position: ", i);
            }
        }

        // Generate and send summary message
        string periodName = "Weekly Summary (Starting " + TimeToStr(starttime, TIME_DATE) + ")";

        string msg = "=== " + periodName + " ===\n\n" +
            "► Total Profit:    " + DoubleToStr(totalProfit, 2) + " ZAR\n" +
            "► Total Loss:      " + DoubleToStr(totalLoss, 2) + " ZAR\n" +
            "► Net Profit:      " + DoubleToStr(totalProfit + totalLoss, 2) + " ZAR\n\n" +
            "=============================\n";
        SendMyMessage(msg);

        msg_ProfitSummary += msg;

        lastProcessedTime = endtime; // Move to the next period
    }

    return msg_ProfitSummary;
}

What I need help with:
Error handling: I’m unsure if the OrderSelect() function is working as expected or if I should add additional checks.
Performance optimization: Are there any performance improvements I can make in the loop that processes orders within each week?
General best practices: Any recommendations on improving the code’s structure or readability would be greatly appreciated!
What I’ve tried:
Debugging the order selection logic and printing outputs to the log.
Manually calculating the start and end time for the week, but the results don't always align as expected.
the result was:

=== Weekly Summary (Starting 2024.05.06) ===
=== Weekly Summary (Starting 2024.05.13) ===
=== Weekly Summary (Starting 2024.05.20) ===
=== Weekly Summary (Starting 2024.05.27) ===

The monthly transition is correctly identified:

=== Monthly Summary (2024.04.01) ===
=== Monthly Summary (2024.05.01) ===
=== Monthly Summary (2024.06.01) ===

